# Directory Traversal With Extension in java

Tags: java, directory, traversal

I'm trying to make a program that Traverses a directory and subdirectories with the specified extension.Here is the code I have so far.I am trying to use endsWith method but because i m passing parameters of file type for recursive calling,i cant use String in the enhanced For Loop.

```
import java.io.File;
```

public class Traverse_Recursively {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File inputFolder = new File("c:/inputFolder");
    traverse(inputFolder, "");
}

public static void traverse(File parentNode, String leftIndent) {
    if (parentNode.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println(leftIndent + parentNode.getName());

        leftIndent += "     ";

        File childNodes[] = parentNode.listFiles();
        for (File childNode : childNodes) {
            traverse(childNode, leftIndent);
        }
    } else {

        System.out.println(leftIndent +"|   --> "+ parentNode.getName());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's the problem? You're not passing or testing any extension there.

Comment: There is another listFiles method where you can pass your extension filter as parameter: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)

Comment: Yes i m not passing any Extension.I want a code For traversing Directories with extensions(txt,zip,png etc) but i dont know how to do so.

Comment: Well, in your `else` clause, test if the file has one of these extensions, and only print it if it does.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Java 7 Files.walkFileTree method - it'll make things much easier I think:

```
    Path path = Paths.get(<your root directory>);
    Files.walkFileTree(path, new FileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("visitFile: " + file.getFileName());
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("postVisitDirectory: " + dir.getFileName());
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
```

If you're only interested in files, you only need to do something in the visitFile method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 6 or earlier you can use apache commons FileUtils or DirectoryWalker for such purpose.